# Large, complex set of objects. Is an ORM what I am looking for?

Tags: java, memory-management

Context: 3d modeling/rendering package. Many types of 3d objects - geometric primitives, various flavors of mesh objects.

Plus POJOs that define textures, materials, etc.

Objects defined in scripts, animation tracks, and all the associated fun stuff.

My Problem: As this package has grown, some of the scenes created by users are reaching the limits of average consumer-grade hardware, esp. memory use.

What I would like to do: Map much of a scene out to disk, only load the portions that are currently being modified into RAM. MemoryMappedByteBuffers can't be used directly, as the objects in a scene all have their own internal data structures, and some are nested.
(a mesh object has a collection of Vertex objects, each of which has a Vector3D object. Any object can have various animation tracks, which have variable numbers of keyframes...etc.)

My question: In digging around for information, I've run across descriptions of ORM systems. Especially SimpleORM. Are these likely to help me? If not, why not? and where might I look for a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend an ORM, because scenes and graphics don't lend themselves to relational models so well.  The JOINing kills you.

I'd suggest a graph or object database.  Querying a deeply nested, recursive graph will be much faster.